# Single module from scipy into python project

Tags: python, module, server, scipy, package

My situation:

need to upload solution `.zip` file to some server where my `solution.py` file gets executed. However, I need to use scipy method from package spatial, which is not available on server.

Simple attach whole `scipy lib` ? - No, I can't beacuse it won't fit in `.zip` file size regulations, however, if I upload only spatial package from scipy (not using any other) everything would fit (size).

Is it possible ?

Because when pasted simply spatial package into my project folder (files from github repo) it didn't work because of errors like `'Couldn't find foofile'` mainly in import instructions.

Thanks, any help appreciated

Comment: That's probably a bad idea as you need to make you got all the dependencies. It's also unclear, which part of spatial you need, maybe a simple function copy-paste is enough. Apart from that, is this allowed within your task?

Comment: Much of `scipy.spatial` is written in C++, C, and Cython, so you definitely cannot install it by simply copying the files from the github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see one reason why this does not work, you can do from the (i)python commandline

```
from scipy import spatial
import inspect
inspect.getsourcelines(spatial)
```

Under the comment text, you can see several imports. If you also look at the first of those,

```
inspect.getsourcelines(spatial.kdtree)
```

there is another import line

```
import scipy.sparse
```

This is just the first example I found, there are surely many more dependencies and scipy.spatial won't work as is if you don't have access to them. Note also that numpy is imported, and if your server does not have scipy, it probably does not have numpy either.

My suggestion is to either copy/rewrite the scipy code you need (if this is allowed), write your code without scipy or ask for the server admin to either allow larger files or install scipy.